# Code to verify if target volume can be achieved from starting volume with given ramp rates

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Programming Problem.

I have a starting volume (in MW) and I need to reach a target Volume (in MW) in a specified amount of time. The ideal solution is to generate a linear line between the points to calculate rate required. However we can only go from the starting rate to the target rate using specified ramp rates:

1. Rate 1 - MW/min from any starting volume to the Elbow Volume 1
2. Elbow Volume 1 - volume at this point
3. Rate 2 - MW/min from Elbow Volume 1 to Elbow Volume 2
4. Elbow Volume 2 - volume at this point
5. Rate 3 - MW/min from Elbow Volume 2 to target volume

So as an example I could have the following:

1. Rate 1 = 10MW/min.
2. Elbow Volume 1 = 100MW
3. Rate 2 = 5MW/min
4. Elbow Volume 2 = 105MW
5. Rate 3 = 35MW/min

[Exzample rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjAj9.png)

This means I can start at any volume before 100MW and get to 100MW @ 10MW/min. I can then get to 105MW @ 5MW/min. I can then achieve any volume greater than 105MW at a rate of 35MW/min.

So if the start volume is 75MW and target volume is 800MW with a time difference of 30 mins is this achievable:

1. Starting from target volume at 750MW I can get to 105MW in 19.9 mins:
     volume delta = 800MW - 105MW = 695MW
     time taken = 695MW / 35(MW/min) = 19.9 mins
2. I can get from 105MW to 100MW in 1 mins
     volume delta = 105MW - 100MW = 5MW
     time taken = 5MW / 5(MW/min) = 1 min
3. I can get from 100MW to 75MW in mins:
     volume delta = 100MW - 75MW = 25MW
     time taken = 25MW / 10(MW/min) = 2.5 mins
4. Time taken in total = 19.9mins + 1min + 2.5mins = 23.4mins
5. Since 23.4mins < 30mins then this is possible

I can program the above steps to verify the above but looking for a efficient way which I may be missing.

The way I have coded this in c# is as follows:

1. Get starting and target volumes.
2. If Elbow Volume 2 >= start volume and Elbow Volume 2 <= target volume then passing through Elbow Volume 2:

   - Calculate volume delta between target and elbow volume 2. Divide by rate 3 to give T1
   - Calculate volume delta between elbow volume 1 and max(start volume, elbow volume 2). Divide by rate 2 to give T2.
3. If Elbow Volume 1 >= start volume and Elbow Volume 1 <= target volume then passing through Elbow 1:

   - Calculate volume delta between start and elbow volume 1. Divide by rate 1 to give T3.

Sum T1, T2 and T3 and verify that is less then time between start and target volume.

I believe this is working but looking to see if there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right from your explanation, you have the following data given:

- target volume
- elbow volume 2
- rate 3
- total time to reach target volume

To make it clear, I will follow the notaion that I made in your example image.

[image]

- you know y<sub>3</sub> (target volume)
- you know y<sub>2</sub> (elbow volume 2)
- you know m<sub>3</sub> (rate 3)
- you know x<sub>3</sub> (total time)

That's all you need to know to find out, if x<sub>2</sub> < x<sub>3</sub>. 
If so, you can reach the target volume in the given time.

Since

m<sub>3</sub> = (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) / (x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>)

<=>

m<sub>3</sub>(x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>) = (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)

<=>

(x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>) = (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) / m<sub>3</sub>

you just need to know if

(y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) / m<sub>3</sub> > 0

because then

(x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>) > 0

So you only need to check, if

(target volume - elbow volume2) divided by rate3 is greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I think I missed a point out here, I have a starting volume and target volume. Now I can go through elbow volume 1 and elbow volume 2 depending on my starting and target volume. If my starting volume is 104 and target is 150 then I will only go through elbow 2 and use rate 2 and 3. If my start volume is 90 and target volume is 104 then I will only go through Elbow 1 and use rates 2 and 3. If my start volume is 90 and target volume is 150 then I will use rate 1 to get from 90 to 100, rate 2 to get from 100 to 105 and rate 3 to get from 105 to 150.